# Melodic minor with raised 4th

Tags: improvisation, modes

I think I heard Bill Evans playing melodic minor with raised 4th over a Dm6/9 chord (on "I do it for your love" with Thielemans). Has anyone encountered this scale elsewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Technically speaking, it is the fourth mode of [harmonic major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_major_scale). It is also called *Lydian b3*, even though it seems much more natural to refer to it the way you did: *melodic minor #4*.

If D is the root, it's a mode of A harmonic major:

`A B C# D E F G#`

However, note that especially in jazz improvisation it's not always helpful to interpret each and every note as part of a scale. Bill Evans (just like all other jazz improvisers) uses chromatic passing tones, approach notes, etc.

It would be necessary to analyze the specific melody to judge whether the raised 4 is actually a scale note or just some form of chromaticism.